# Querying data from a website using R and GET function

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am very new to web scraping and I need to download data that appears a couple of clics after making a query. This means that i need to fill up two fields in the first page, then clic on a text in **bold** and then identify a table of data in upper case, and download it.

I started with using the GET function and adding the required names as a list to the "query"argument. However, despite i am an old R user, I can not even decipher the error i got.

```
GET("http://apps.kew.org/wcsp/advsearch.do;jsessionid=15925570A99B794122939889DE7DCDBC",path = "search", query =list(Genus="Imperata",Species="cylindrica"))


Response[http://apps.kew.org/search;jsessionid=15925570A99B794122939889DE7DCDBC?      Genus=Imperata&Species=cylindrica]
```

Date: 2016-04-18 18:29
  Status: 404
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  Size: 445 B
    
    
    404 Not Found

## Not Found

The requested URL /search;jsessionid=15925570A99B794122939889DE7DCDBC was     not   found ...

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
    error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the   request.

---

Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at apps.kew.org Port 80

Comment: It was even impossible to format the error in a decent way!

Comment: Please provide more information. For instance, what package are you using? Also, in your tags, I think you are confusing `GET` with `get`. `get` is a separate function in R that is not related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be not working as it's a `POST` request vs a `GET` request (you can use my `curlconverter` package to help with these "hidden" APIs, btw):

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

res <- httr::POST(url = "http://apps.kew.org/wcsp/advsearch.do", 
           body = list(page = "advancedSearch", 
                       AttachmentExist = "", 
                       family = "", 
                       placeOfPub = "", 
                       genus = "Imperata", 
                       yearPublished = "", 
                       species = "cylindrica", 
                       author = "", 
                       infraRank = "", 
                       infraEpithet = "", 
                       selectedLevel = "cont"), 
           encode = "form") 


pg <- content(res, as="parsed")

html_text(html_nodes(pg, "a.onwardnav"))

##  [1] "Imperata cylindrica (L.) P.Beauv., Ess. Agrostogr.: 165 (1812)."                                                
##  [2] "Imperata cylindrica var. africana (Andersson) C.E.Hubb., Joint Publ. Imp. Agric. Bur. 7: 10 (1944)."            
##  [3] "Imperata cylindrica var. condensata (Steud.) Hack., Anales Mus. Nac. Hist. Nat. Buenos Aires 21: 9 (1911)."     
##  [4] "Imperata cylindrica var. europaea (Andersson) Asch. & Graebn., Syn. Mitteleur. Fl. 2(1): 37 (1898)."            
##  [5] "Imperata cylindrica subsp. koenigii (Retz.) Masamura & Yanagih., Trans. Nat. Hist. Soc. Formosa 31: 326 (1941)."
##  [6] "Imperata cylindrica subvar. koenigii (Retz.) T.Durand & Schinz, Consp. Fl. Afric. 5: 694 (1894)."               
##  [7] "Imperata cylindrica var. koenigii (Retz.) Pilg., Fragm. Fl. Philipp. 1: 137 (1904)."                            
##  [8] "Imperata cylindrica var. latifolia (Hook.f.) C.E.Hubb., Joint Publ. Imp. Agric. Bur. 7: 14 (1944)."             
##  [9] "Imperata cylindrica var. major (Nees) C.E.Hubb., Grasses Mauritius: 96 (1940)."                                 
## [10] "Imperata cylindrica var. mexicana (Rupr. ex Galeotti) D.B.Ward, Novon 14: 368 (2004)."                          
## [11] "Imperata cylindrica f. pallida Honda, J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo, Sect. 3, Bot. 3: 374 (1930)."                   
## [12] "Imperata cylindrica var. parviflora Batt. & Trab., Bull. Soc. Bot. France 53: 32 (1906)."                       
## [13] "Imperata cylindrica var. pedicellata (Steud.) Debeaux, Actes Soc. Linn. Bordeaux 32: 52 (1878)."                
## [14] "Imperata cylindrica var. thunbergii (Retz.) T.Durand & Schinz, Consp. Fl. Afric. 5: 693 (1894), nom. superfl."  

lnks <- html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a.onwardnav"), "href")

res2 <- GET(sprintf("http://apps.kew.org%s", lnks[1]))
pg2 <- content(res2, as="parsed")

trimws(gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", html_text(html_nodes(pg2, "th + td"))))

## [1] "Medit. to Africa and Afghanistan 12 BAL COR FRA POR SAR SPA 13 ALB BUL GRC ITA KRI SIC TUE YUG 20 ALG EGY LBY MOR TUN 21 CNY CVI MDR 22 BEN BKN GAM GHA GNB GUI IVO LBR MLI NGA NGR SEN SIE TOG 23 BUR CAF CMN CON EQG GAB GGI RWA ZAI 24 CHA ETH SOC SUD 25 KEN TAN UGA 26 ANG MLW MOZ ZAM ZIM 27 BOT CPP LES NAM NAT OFS SWZ TVL 29 COM MAU MDG (32) kaz kgz tkm tzk uzb (33) ncs tcs 34 AFG CYP EAI IRN IRQ LBS PAL SIN TUR 35 KUW OMA? SAU YEM (36) chc chh chi chm chn chs cht chx (38) jap kor nns oga tai (40) ass ban ehm ind nep pak srl whm (41) and cbd lao mya ncb scs tha vie (42) bor cki jaw lsi mly mol phi sul sum xms (43) bis nwg sol (50) nfk (51) nzn (60) fij nwc sam ton van wal (62) mrn (73) ore (77) tex (78) ala fla geo lou msi sca vrg (79) mxs mxt"
## [2] "Hemicr. or rhizome geophyte"    
## [3] "Poaceae"                                     
## [4] "W.D.Clayton, R.Govaerts, K.T.Harman, H.Williamson & M.Vorontsova"
```

Comment: Thanks! that takes me to the link list. Now i am trying to figure out how to access the first link. Looking at your package for that.

Comment: no need for `curlconverter` for that :-) [amended answer]

Comment: just one more related question, what means "a.onwardnav"? Is it a CSS selector? In some cases,(ex. the species "Arctodupontia scleroclada"),  the script does not retrieve any link, but the website works when using that name. I thought it might be due to an inappropriate CSS selector.

Comment: aye, that's a CSS selector that I grabbed from looking at the page in Dev Tools. There may be a way to make it more generic.

Comment: Using different selectors (".plantname" or "td") that i found using the selectorgadget app didnt work. I mean, I could get this:                html_nodes(pg, ".plantname")
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <h2 class="plantname"><i>Ã— Arctodupontia</i><i> scleroclada</i> (Rupr.) Tzvelev, N ...                                                                                  but that is not recognisable by html_attr. The new question is here:                                                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727606/identify-the-correct-css-selector-of-a-url-for-an-r-script