# Issue with scraping data from form, on a website with cookies

Tags: r, rvest

I'm regularly using a website to download updated data and thought it would make sense to automate the process... so I've started to look into the `rvest`package.
After several attempts based on other stackoverflow posts (e.g. [Querying data from a website using R and GET function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702843/querying-data-from-a-website-using-r-and-get-function), [Unable to scrape website with form using rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283185/unable-to-scrape-website-with-form-using-rvest) etc.) - which seem to be based on fairly similar websites as the one I'm interested in - I'm starting to wonder if this is possible...

Here is the website: https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fleet-europa/index_en

To begin with, one has to accept all cookies before proceeding, but I haven't found how to do so...
In the `Search` tab, I'd then like to download and load the csv (not the incomplete records available through the `Search` button at the bottom of the form) available through the `Download` button, for all countries, the entire period, and the whole history, but I can't seem to be able to find the correct references to use, as in the examples quoted above... These seemed to be a little more straightforward.

Would anyone be able to help me on this? Is this even possible? I've already run into websites that do not allow **scraping**, so this is hopefully not one of those :)

Cheers,

Comment: Are you using `GET` or are you using `html_session`? It's a bit difficult to help much without seeing what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I've started with html_session and later looked into GET and POST as well, but I'm not even sure what to use. I'm a true beginner in rvest and it's all a bit cloudy... I guess I'm open to any solution that will allow me to accept the cookies and then download the data I want

Comment: The robots.txt has that scraping disallowed. Whenever you're going to scrape, it's important to look at what they allow. You can find the allow and disallow [here](https://ec.europa.eu/robots.txt).